# Is "banker friend" a noun adjunct, or something else?

Tags: phrases, nouns, attributive-nouns

Consider the sentence:

> I have a banker friend, and she says that interest rates are going up.

Here *a banker friend* is being used to mean *a friend who is a banker*.    Is there a name for this kind of construction?

It is similar to a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct), but it seems to me the examples there don't seem to fit this case exactly.  In those, the pair (or sequence) of nouns stands in for a prepositional phrase, but in *a friend who is a banker* there is no preposition.  The notion of a noun adjunct would seem to apply better to a sentence like

> The new finance minister is well known as a banker friend.

Here *banker friend* stands for the prepositional phrase *a friend of bankers*.  That seems quite different from my first example.

Comment: A contradiction in terms, no?

Comment: @deadrat you beat me to it ...

Answer (score 1):

Your link says it all [(cf also Apposition/ Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition); You are right in your first example and wrong in your second.

If the person mentioned is primarily a *friend*, you are correct in saying

> I have a **banker friend**, and she says that interest rates are going up.

If the person is primarily a *banker*, say

> I have a **friendly banker**, and she says that interest rates are going
>   up.

If you want to say that the Minister is friendly towards bankers, say

> The new finance minister is well known as a **bankers' friend**.

Answer (score 0):

Banker friend would still be a noun adjunct, because, as the link shows, noun adjuncts merely require that the modifier be optional and a noun.

So, noun adjuncts do not require a replacement prepositional phrase.